# How to access Form properties from a separate thread in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli

In my application i am going to do some producer consumer work. In my Form application I produce items and save it to array which is a property of the Form object. My consumer should run on a separate thread by consuming items that produced by the Form object. How do i implement this??

Comment: this is a bad design. i would consider a redesign where the form doesn't own the data.

Comment: Could suggest a design or sample project since i'm really new to C++/CLI

Comment: what do you have experience programming in?

Comment: I have done threading in C++..It just I'm not sure how to do it in C++/CLI

Answer (score 0):

If this array contains objects not related to UI, you can access them directly, this means, use this form property from any thread. To synchronize multi-thread access, use mutex.

For any UI-related stuff, use Control.BeginInvoke or Control.Invoke.

Comment: Thankx alot...I didn't knew that before. can u show me a snippet showing how ti create a thread and access Form properties